# How to add step by step guidance mechanism to android

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to add a user guide to my android application when app first start like this

[image]

How I do this kind of user guide navigation, is there is any other way?

Comment: If my answer is solved your question. Just tick my answer as accepted. Thanks @user3480706

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implement this Showcase Library in my project successfully.

https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView

load this library at Main Activity's Oncreate first time using SharedPreferences.

```
public class classname extends AppCompatActivity 
{
 public SharedPreferences settings;
 public SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
 public boolean firstRun;

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  settings = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME", 0);
  editor = settings.edit();

  firstRun= settings.getBoolean("FIRST_RUN", false);
   //FIRST_RUN as false by default. 
  if (!firstRun) {

   // Load your showcase at first time

         editor.putBoolean("FIRST_RUN", true);
         editor.commit();
  //saves FIRST_RUN as true, so it will run only at first time

   }

 }
}
```